# Removing the prompt for credentials from CRM SDK dataimport sample

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I've been using the data import SDK sample to upload a csv into a custom entity for a few weeks now, all works great.

Im looking at getting it a little more automated, so is there a way to remove the prompt to select the previously saved credentials?

ATM i get this every time I load dataimport.exe:

```
(0) Add New Server Configuration (Maximum number up to 9)
(1) Server: xxxxxxxx, Org: xxxxxxx, User: xxxxxx
Specify the saved server configuration number (1-1) [1] : 1
```

Obviously it would always be option 1

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One way to enable "headless" operation is to store the connection string in a text file and encrypt that text file using Windows encryption.

For example...

File contents (connection string):
`Url=https://myOrg.crm.dynamics.com; Username=me@myOrg.onmicrosoft.com; Password=myPassword; AuthType=Office365; RequireNewInstance=true;`

To encrypt it, right click on the file and go to Properties > Advanced and select Encrypt Contents to Secure Data.

[image: encrypt]

Then in your application you have to find the part where it prompts for the organization info and creates the `IOrganizationService` instance (which depending on the age of your sample code might be a combination of a `CrmConnection` instance and an `OrganizationServiceProxy` or something like that)

Instead of what you have right now you can simply instantiate a `CrmServiceClient` with the connection string from the file.

```
var connectionFilePath = @"c:\temp\connection\smyOrgConnection.txt";
var connectionString = File.ReadAllText(connectionFilePath); 
var svc = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);
```

Your service instance may be named something other than `svc`. For a smooth transition you may want to assign the instance of `CrmServiceClient` to the existing variable.

Assuming that the existing service implements `IOrganizationService`, everything should work fine with the instance of `CrmServiceClient`.

Admittedly this is a little abstract. To make it concrete you'd have to post the relevant code.